# Order table randomly but with exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which I need to sort randomly, but some rows need to stick together.

For example, the table is generated like this

[image: From this]

All the rows which have the CATEGORY = C and CODE = 101 need to be in sequence(one after the other), but at random position in the general order. Others rows need to be randomly sorted.

[image: Like this]

It's possible to do this only with "order by"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @exceptionOrder uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

SELECT ID, Category, Code
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Category = 'C' AND Code = 101 THEN @exceptionOrder ELSE NEWID() END
```

This will assign the same `uniqueidentifier` to the exception rows, a random `uniqueidentifier` to each of the rest of the rows, then order by them.

Comment: Good thinking, I tried a few selects and it's doing exactly what a needed, thanks!

Comment: @MarceloCarvalhoNascimento NP, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select 
    id, category, code, name
  from (
  select
      case when rand() > 0.5 then 2 + rand() else rand() end as sort_order,
      id, category, code, name
    from my_table
    where CATEGORY <> 'C' or CODE <> 101
  union
  select
      1 as sort_order,
      id, category, code, name
    from my_table
    where CATEGORY = 'C' and CODE = 101
  ) x
  order by sort_order
```