# Cross joining a single row subquery with a column using `newid()` results in every row having a different GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server, uuid

**Abstract**

A query like

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT newid() guid) x;
```

in SQL Server produces a result where every row has a different GUID instead of every row having a common GUID throughout the result. How to have one GUID for all rows of the result (without using a variable or (temporary) table)?

**Setup**

Consider the following table in an SQL Server database.

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (id integer);

INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO elbat
            VALUES (6);
```

Let's run the following query.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT newid() guid) x;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=90cf0a1dbaae37496c784049aa1f8463) and an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97901/1) to see it in action.

**Problem**

Much to my surprise, in the result every row has a different GUID. E.g.:

```
 id | guid                                
 -: | :-----------------------------------
  1 | ad146af7-9ebd-4521-a440-47c7dea6a1d4
  2 | ce24fbb8-af64-480c-8c46-1e03187642c5
  3 | 14509451-9b1d-49e9-8da2-c691947ae805
  4 | 37a86339-e352-486f-b541-92798540599f
  5 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  6 | d491275b-4ebb-461b-94e2-93b47e7d2348
```

That left me puzzled. I'd expected every row to have the same GUID throughout the whole result set. E.g.:

```
 id | guid                                
 -: | :-----------------------------------
  1 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  2 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  3 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  4 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  5 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
  6 | cbee1a8e-02ce-4915-8d2c-ef5db299d8c8
```

Of course I understand, that the GUID will change from call to call. But I don't understand why it changes from row to row as I cross joined a single GUID and didn't put the `newid()` call in the list of projected columns.

**Additional information**

I tried this with all available versions on the fiddle platforms and additionally with a local Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2269.0 (X64), Express). The result is the same everywhere (only the GUIDs change of course).

Questioning my understanding of joins, I also did some tests on other DBMS with an equivalent setup and query.

- (DDL and DML stay the same for all of them.)
- Postgres:

  ```
  SELECT *
         FROM elbat t
              CROSS JOIN (SELECT uuid_generate_v4() guid) x;
  ```

  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/97901/1)
- Oracle:

  ```
  SELECT *
         FROM elbat t
              CROSS JOIN (SELECT sys_guid() guid
                                 FROM dual) x;
  ```

  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc9dba48c415169a23b5c0b6967d1c14)
- MariaDB:

  ```
  SELECT *
         FROM elbat t
              CROSS JOIN (SELECT uuid() guid) x;
  ```

  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8ccedba8b71269033c5a0ccc8cda7d46)
- MySQL:

  ```
  SELECT *
         FROM elbat t
              CROSS JOIN (SELECT uuid() guid) x;
  ```

  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97901/1)

All of these other DBMS produce a result as I actually expect -- one common GUID in all rows of the result.

I also played around changing the query. To no avail though.

- Put the subquery in a CTE.
- I tried selecting from a physical table in the subquery, rather than the `SELECT` without a `FROM`, using `TOP` and also a primary key.
- Using an implicit cross join (`FROM elbat, (SELECT newid() ...)`).
- Using `CROSS APPLY`.

Looking up the documentation, I couldn't find this behavior covered anywhere.

**Question**

Why does SQL Server behave different than all the other (tested) DBMS (in that regard) and is there a way to get a result as expected (without using a variable or (temporary) table)?

(Note: I know I could use a variable initialized with `newid()` and have it in the projected columns. But The problem actually arose while I was trying to avoid such a variable. I actually wanted to look for a variable-less, query-only solution for ["Order table randomly but with exceptions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314103/order-table-randomly-but-with-exceptions).)

Comment: I would have expected SQL Server to behave like the other databases.  The rule is that the subqueries in the `FROM` clause should be evaluated only once.

Comment: . . I wish I could upvote the question more than once.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209084/sql-server-splits-a-b-into-a-b-or-a-b-yielding-strange-results-if-b-is-n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am really surprised at the SQL Server behavior.  I did not realize that it re-evaluates such subqueries over-and-over.  I suspect the cause is an optimization:  the expression in the `cross join` is actually moved to the the node that reads the data, so the function is called over and over.

In any case, I consider this wrong.  Such an optimization should recognize that `newid()` is a volatile function and adjust accordingly.

After some experimentation, I figured out that `order by` in the subquery does cause it to be evaluated only once.  So, this does what you want:

```
select *
from elbat cross join
     (select top (1) newid() as guid
      order by guid
     ) x;
```

Another version that does what you expect:

```
select *
from elbat cross join
     (select max(newid()) as guid
     ) x;
```

Incidentally, this latter version works in the `select` as well:

```
select *, (select max(newid())) as guid
from elbat ;
```

And in this case, I would expect the subquery to be evaluated once for every row.  Go figure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to an archive of the Connect issue (alas now defunct), discussing whether to "fix" this behavior. Reproduced here to preserve the information.  This is the feedback from the SQL Dev team on closing the reported issue as "Won't Fix":

> “Closing the loop . . . I've discussed this question with the Dev
>   team. And eventually we have decided not to change current behavior,
>   for the following reasons:
>
> 1) The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of
>   scalar functions. This is a long-established tenet. It's the
>   fundamental 'leeway' that allows the optimizer enough freedom to gain
>   significant improvements in query-plan execution.
>
> 2) This "once-per-row behavior" is not a new issue, although it's not
>   widely discussed. We started to tweak its behavior back in the Yukon
>   release. But it's quite hard to pin down precisely, in all cases,
>   exactly what it means! For example, does it a apply to interim rows
>   calculated 'on the way' to the final result? - in which case it
>   clearly depends on the plan chosen. Or does it apply only to the rows
>   that will eventually appear in the completed result? - there's a nasty
>   recursion going on here, as I'm sure you'll agree!
>
> 3) As I mentioned earlier, we default to "optimize performance" -
>   which is good for 99% of cases. The 1% of cases where it might change
>   results are fairly easy to spot - side-effecting 'functions' such as
>   NEWID - and easy to 'fix' (trading perf, as a consequence). This
>   default to "optimize performance" again, is long-established, and
>   accepted. (Yes, it's not the stance chosen by compilers for
>   conventional programming languages, but so be it).
>
> So, our recommendations are:
>
> a) Avoid reliance on non-guaranteed timing and number-of-executions
>   semantics.
>
> b) Avoid using NEWID() deep in table expressions.
>
> c) Use OPTION to force a particular behavior (trading perf)
>
> Hope this explanation helps clarify our reasons for closing this bug
>   as "won't fix".
>
> Thanks,
>
> Jim”

https://web.archive.org/web/20160626085155/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions

Comment: @DavidBrown-Microsoft . . . This should really be fixed.  It is not that hard to identify volatile functions in such subqueries.

Comment: Here's the new feedback link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

A cte (without recursion) is just a way to make queries with subqueries more readable for us humans. SQL Server seems to be too clever and just adds a calculated column, no matter how we write the query. But this way, using an outer join, I tricked him and made him JOIN using nested loops:

```
WITH x (guid) AS (
  SELECT newid()
)
SELECT *
FROM elbat t
  RIGHT JOIN x ON x.guid IS NOT NULL;
```